# How do I refresh the Firebase Provider Access Token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a Firebase method to access and refresh the OAuth Provider token, similar to the Firebase ID Token?

I'm using Firebase Auth with Microsoft as my provider. Firebase returns two tokens:

- **Provider Access Token:** this is the Microsoft token that I can use to make calls to Microsoft APIs
- **Firebase ID Token:** this is the Firebase Auth token that I can use to access Google resources

I'm using `signInWithRedirect` and `getRedirectResult` to access these tokens:

```
signInWithRedirect(authInstance, provider)

# ...later in the file handle redirect
const result = await getRedirectResult(authInstance)
if (result) {
  const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)
  const accessToken = credential?.accessToken
  const idToken = credential?.idToken
}
```

There is an easy method to access the Firebase ID token that will automatically refresh it if expires, for example: `authInstance.currentUser.getIdToken()`. I'm having to set the `accessToken` in a cookie because there doesn't appear to be a method to retrieve it from Firebase. After one hour, the accessToken expires and I need to refresh it.

I can't find an easy way to retrieve and refresh the Provider Access Token outside of the `getRedirectResult()`. The `OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult()` method receives a `UserCredential` type that only seems to be returned after logging in.

How have others solved this issue -- how do you access and refresh the Provider Token in a place after the initial login?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: I discovered it isn't possible to refresh the provider token using Firebase libraries, you would need to refresh it manually or use the provider libraries. In my case, I ended up using both the Microsoft and Firebase libraries to manage two separate tokens. I login to Microsoft with their library, extract the claims, then create a new token with Firebase's `.createCustomToken()` that includes the Microsoft claims data. That way, custom claims can be written to the Firebase user record.